# How do I file a complaint about a user?

Tags: support, users, offensive

I feel like I have found an amazingly rude user on the SE network. I would like to file a complaint about that user but I don't know what that user needs to have done wrong or how to do it.

This user has not done anything wrong on the surface, but often blatantly disrespects comments against himself. How and should I attempt to get rid of that user?

Comment: It's best not to call out people on Meta. The best thing to do is to find one of the user's posts (especially one that's problematic) and flag the post using the "other" option to explain the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't trust anyone hide behind a sock puppet ... or anyone who only has a meta account then complain about another user on a different site. Sorry, it's just my habit of doubting something when someone has something to hide ...

Comment: Did he accuse you of being part of a grand conspiracy run by Jeff Atwood to keep him down? If so, that's just his standard greeting.

Comment: @BradLarson How'd you know!

Comment: @chmod666telkitty Ah, I just prefer using my Math account. See I use SE by iPhone and my fat fingers can often touch the other accounts by mistake. By "hiding" my accounts, it just separates the accounts out. That makes it easier to touch for me. If it is a problem, which it seems to be, I will I hide all accounts for you. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: I had three guesses for who the user was.  I wasn't right, because this wasn't about me :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you believe a comment to be offensive, mouse over it and press the red flag icon that appears. There is an "offensive" flag reason. Basically, to be considered offensive, content has to be in violation of the [Be Nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

If there is a more extensive problem (that requires a lot of explanation/evidence), raise a flag on one of your own posts and provide details. Questions about behavior patterns could go on Meta, but I would suggest not calling people out.

You might also *tell the other person how you feel*, probably done best in chat, but a reply comment might be appropriate. Make sure you respond kindly no matter how you feel.